# WhatsApp Infinite Loops

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, mobile, marketingcloudapi

I´ve been a marketing cloud user for almost a year now, so I believe I´m still a beginner regarding some subjects, specially the latest features like WhatsApp.
I am currently trying to set up a Journey only with WhatsApp messages and I´m facing a difficulty that I suspect there´s a simple solution.

The Journey´s basic logic is:

```
Message 1 -> YES, NO or INVALID ANSWER -> Message 2 -> YES, NO or INVALID ANSWER -> and so on....
```

Now, every time I receive an INVALID ANSWER from the customer, I need to send them a message asking to repeat the answer from the previous message with a YES or NO.

**Problem:** I need to repeat this at least 10 times before I give up sending messages to this customer and eject him from the journey. How do I do this? Is there any kind of "Infinite loop" that is configurable on Journey Builder?

I found this article that says something similar exists (or existed) for SMS messages: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_rn_july_2020_moc_inbound_loop.htm&type=%205

The work around I´m using right now is setting up consecutive "Wait Until Chat Response" activities and "joins" until I receive the YES or NO answer, but doing this with 5 consecutive invalid answers from each question is making my Journey too big! (Over 100 activities in total).

Does anyone have any guidelines for this?

Best Regards,

Conrado

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have only rather general advice because this a general problem. Since you're asking for guidelines, I hope this helps somewhat, even though it is not a "solution" that I am offering.

There is no infinite loop capability that is made visually obvious.
(For rather apparent reasons if you think what that could do to a database / performance, when put in the hands of thousands of users.) What you linked to is an attempt to prohibit this from happening.

What you are running into is a typical problem of a visual point and click interface, it grows out of hand when things become repetitive. You need more abstraction and you cannot drag and drop that onto a canvas.

What that means is:
The more repetitions you need, the less suitable your process becomes for a Journey that is inspired by / structured with the frontend / UI in mind.

In other words, you need some code, you'll need a small data extension infrastructure to track customer statuses and you'll need recursion (a process that sends based on a user status, changes the user status, returns to its own start).

If you will, a journey that sends, updates and "calls itself", and also makes sure to break this loop.

Your main problem will become how to execute your code at the right time, as you are likely interested in a rather fast repetition where necessary. This takes automation studio out of the picture, with its hourly repetition that you'd already have to "hack" a workaround for.

In such a result your "journey" will probably just contain the message and a creative way to execute code. AMPScript is an option for Whatsapp messages.
Without code, you might reach your goal but your journey will be pain setting up and maintaining.

Comment: Thank you for the answer @JonasLamberty.
I´m still not very familiar with AMPScript, but I think now would be a good time to learn more about it.

Comment: Regarding WhatsApp functionality in general, I am very frustrated with all the limitations that it currently presents.
The only WhatsApp report that Marketing Cloud provides (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=sf.mc_jb_whatsapp_data_extract.htm&type=5) is not working right now, 
according to this: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/issues_view?title=whatsapp-tracking-extract-fails-to-run&Id=a1p4V000001U5PY.
So if I activate my WhatsApp journey right now, I will not be able to know what happened to each message I sent.